# Image exists on remote URL but curl give me 404 status

Tags: php, curl, url-rewriting, server, http-status-code-404

I have a WordPress site where we are facing some issues using images.

The images exist on the server, when we access the images via URL, it works and the image shows.

But when we use curl, file_get_contents, fopen, copy etc command to get or access the file, we get the 404 error status code.

Can anyone can help me, I don't know if it's a server issue or WordPress issue.

Below is my sample of code:

```
$url = "http://blogbucket.in/wp-content/uploads/files/0B6IGyYw9A5RYS0tNelJrdmFsMTQ/airbitz-co1.png";
$ch = @curl_init($url);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
@curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

@curl_exec($ch);
$header = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($header);
echo "<pre>";
```

Below are the links I've looked at so far.

- [Check whether image exists on remote URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363925/check-whether-image-exists-on-remote-url)
- [How to check if a file exists from a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-a-url)
- [cURL is returning 404 on a file that exists (remote server). Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283476/curl-is-returning-404-on-a-file-that-exists-remote-server-why)
- [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)
- [How to check if an URL exists with the shell and probably curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199059/how-to-check-if-an-url-exists-with-the-shell-and-probably-curl)
- [PHP Detecting if source image url link leads to a "broken" image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677965/php-detecting-if-source-image-url-link-leads-to-a-broken-image)

You can try it [here](http://blogbucket.in/wp-content/uploads/files/0B6IGyYw9A5RYS0tNelJrdmFsMTQ/airbitz-co1.png).

Comment: We need to see your code, make an example using PHP Curl and post it so we can see what you're attempting to do

Comment: @zack6849 sure, i'll update my question.

Comment: why you guys downgrade my question, if you think your are good in it, then resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> The images exist on the server, when we access the images via URL, it works and the image shows.
>
> But when we use curl, file_get_contents, fopen, copy etc command to get or access the file, we get the 404 error status code.

This url returns 404 response with image payload. So you can disregard the response code and use the image data from the response body.

Comment: I don't have any issue with it.... facebook and other SEO platforms have an issue with this thing.